Integrate Quarkus and quarkus-oidc with Android Authenticate
Currently have an application that works great with a Node front end and a Quarkus backend.
For authentication we have been using Google Credentials as our OIDC server, and the quarkus-oidc library to take care of all the authentication calls for us.
We recently have tried to create an Android application that just uses WebView to display our main app, and takes advantage of Android Authenticate:
https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg
But we have having issues integrating the Web Token we get from the Android application to our app. Seems like Quarkus OIDC is maybe encrypting the token it sends back and forth? We noticed when we plugged the q_session value we are getting from our backend into a JWT decoder it does not give any information.
Does anyone have any experience with Quarkus integration into Android around authentication?
Thanks!
